# Test EventBridge hourly schedule - Trigger immediatly

Tags: aws-event-bridge

I've configured and AWS EventBridge schedule that triggers a lambda target every hour.

How can I best test this trigger without having to wait until the schedule is reaching 1 hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime things are simple....
The Lambda interface actually provides a Test function with with you can generate events:
[image]

I guess I looked in the wrong place to generate events (in the eventbridge itself).

Comment: Life saver! This will save me a lot of time! Thank you.

Comment: I have signed in to Stack Overflow to upvote this answer. Life saver!